# Write web services with existing Laravel Controllers

Tags: php, web-services, rest, laravel-5, postman

I have a project in `Laravel 5.2` and now I have to make the `APIs` for that. I tried to hit the `localhost/myproject/login` via postman as a post request with the parameters but it returns me the `HTML` in return. I have used Laravel's auth scaffolding for the authorization. 
I am unable to find `postLogin` function in my project. 
I have separated the routes but how can I change the existing functions for the API?

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function()
{
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@postLogin');
});
```

Comment: Hi I am not sure why you are trying to hit the localhost/myproject/login via postman for user login.
I think you should hit the localhost/myproject/api/v1/login for this code snippet.

Comment: okay, but how can I edit the postLogin function to return me the `JSON` ?

Comment: You can use JWT token authentication for user login.

Comment: @baig772 can you attach the image of response from the server on postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the postLogin that returns the json rather than the html code.

```
public function authenticate()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        //return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        return response()->json(['status' => 1]);
    }
}
```

If you have any trouble, let me know.